# Many-to-One - Symfony doesn't generate proper ID-based relation

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine-orm

`Tag` table has a relation to the `Category` table as Many-to-One (many tags are related to one category, or one category has many tags).

I should get normal Many-to-One relation from table `Tag` to the table `Category`. It should be based on the ID from the table `Category` (which is named `id_category`). However, instead I'm getting... a `VARCHAR(255)` column in table `Tag`!

Here's part of code from Tag entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_category", referencedColumnName="id_category")
 */
protected $category;
```

Category entity doesn't have appropriate related "tag" column, because it's uni-directional relation. Anyway, here's how `id_category` is declared in the `Category` entity (though I don't think it's important):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id_category;
```

The result I'm getting by the Doctrine2's command `update --dump-sql` is the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Tag ADD category VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
```

Doctrine gives me `VARCHAR`, instead of `INTEGER` as id with foreign key. Does anyone know why?
How to *tell* Symfony to make a relation in this case?

Comment: My old name, I have edited it. Any clue?

Comment: It's not related to SF2 but to Doctrine2 as the command belongs to `DoctrineORMBundle`. Something strange is that the updated field should be named `id_category`, not `category`...

Comment: See my answer, it created a "category" field because of the @ORM\Column annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don´t use @ORM\Column, just @ORM\ManyToOne:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_category", referencedColumnName="id_category", nullable=true)
 */
protected $category;
```

Comment: Thanx Carlos, however what if I want to have Tags with no Category (no Id / relation to Category then)? I hoped that "nullable=true" will help to achieve this purpose.

Comment: Updated answer. You can set nullable=true in the JoinColumn definition

Comment: Though by default relations are nullable in Doctrine, so you don´t really need this. You would need it if you wanted to declare nullable=false